# How I can do this in c#?

Tags: c#

The structure is

- A product has a list of categories.
- categories have a list of pieceinfo
- And every pieceinfo has an Id which I want to check if it exists in product or not.

I have a list `int List<int> pieceinfo` which I want to get from the `List<product>`.

Can someone please tell me how I can do this?

I want to write a `lambda expression` to check if that `pieceinfo` exists or not.

```
Model.Find(x => x.Categories.Find(y => y.PieceInfo.Find(z => z.Id == i)))
```

I want to know how I can check that if every product's categories' `pieceinfo` has an `Id` which is also present in `list<int> i`.

```
public struct Product
{
    public int Id;
    public string Title;
    public List<Productdetailed> Info;
    public List<ProductCategory> Categories;
}

public struct ProductCategory
{
    public int Id;
    public string Title;
    public bool Has_Image;
    public List<ProductInfo> PieceInfo;
    public int ProdId;
}

/// <summary>
/// Coverage, packing detailed
/// </summary>
public struct ProductInfo
{
    public int Id;
    public string Size;
    public string Packing;
    public string Price;
    public bool PricePerTon;
    public int ProdId;
    public int Cat_Id;
}

public struct Productdetailed
{
    public int Id;
    public string Packaging;
    public string Coverage;
    public int prodId;
}
```

Comment: Your post is *very* hard to follow at the moment. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and edit appropriately - including some code if possible.

Comment: one min sir, I will update it. thanks for telling me the issue

Comment: Please post (simplified) class definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var allPieces = Model.SelectMany(x => x.Categories).SelectMany(y => y.PieceInfo);
var isPieceExist = allPieces.Any(piece => piece.Id == id);

// or

var findedPiece  = allPieces.FirstOrDefault(piece => piece.Id == id);
```